# Check the bandwidth rate in Android

Tags: android, bandwidth, codec

We have an option to check the network connection types in Android (whether it is 3G, edge or gprs).

I need to check the the bandwidth rate. I need to initiate a call. For that I need to check the bandwidth rate. Above a particular bandwidth only I need to make visible an option for a call (to initiate a call).

I need to find the connection speed programmatically (connection speed for Mobile Data Link, EDGE).

Answer (score 17):

You can download a known-size file from your server, and calculate how long did it take to download it. Then you have your bandwidth. Simple but works :)

Sample, not tested :

```
//Download your image
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(new URL(urlString).toURI());
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity;
bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

//You can re-check the size of your file
final long contentLength = bufHttpEntity.getContentLength();

// Log
Log.d(TAG, "[BENCHMARK] Dowload time :"+(endTime-startTime)+" ms");

// Bandwidth : size(KB)/time(s)
float bandwidth = contentLength / ((endTime-startTime) *1000);
```

Comment: i need to find the connection speed programmatically in Android

Comment: BTW this is also programmatically

Comment: The biggest your file is, the more precise the test is going to be, but obviously the longest it will be. In my opinion, a good compromise would be 50KB.

Comment: Also if time taken is 0 seconds then what will be bandwidth, we are dividing by zero.

Comment: Well... I don't think a download can take 0 ms but yes that would be wise to check

Comment: @CamilleR do you know a way to calculate this while the file is being downloaded? Is there a way to see how much the download speed is?

Comment: @Elmac : You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932821/httpclient-post-with-progress-and-multipartentitybuilder to get the progress of the download; and see how long it took to download this %/size to know the current download speed

Answer (score 7):

This will  Returns the current link speed in `LINK_SPEED_UNITS.`

but this work for `WIFI Only`

```
WifiManager wifiManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (wifiInfo != null) {
    Integer linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
}
```

Comment: I need to check the connection speed for Mobile Data Link ( mainly EDGE)

Comment: Also, this method only returns the theoretical maximum link speed of current associated Wi-Fi AP, which is 54 mbps normally for most APs.

Comment: linkSpeed coming from kbps or mbps?

Answer (score 0):

Try facebook network library class (library size = 16 KB)

We can fetch manually / network change listener also available.

**Manual fetch code:**

> ConnectionQuality cq =
>   ConnectionClassManager.getInstance().getCurrentBandwidthQuality();

Github link - https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class