# Better way of detecting device bandwidth [Android]

Tags: android, bandwidth

I am writing one network application which downloads multiple files from the server using HTTP protocol.

I want to detect client to server network bandwidth and i am confused in between using the perfect/proper way of calculating bandwidth.

**1.** In my application i am downloading multiple file of different sizes from the remote server. so can i use this file download (and the bytes downloaded) process for calculating the bandwidth? formula that i am using `contantLength / ((downloadEnd-downloadStart)* 1000))`

**OR**

**2.** Should i download a different temporary file (suppose of 50 KB) irrespective of my other downloads just for calculating the bandwidth and then calculate bandwidth?

Which method will provide the reliable bandwidth detection and also which method is efficient.

*NOTE:*
I don't want to detect whether i am connected to internet or not also i don't want to detect the WIFI speed, just want to know proper way of detecting bandwidth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check the bandwidth rate in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225791/check-the-bandwidth-rate-in-android)

Comment: But i do know how to detect bandwidth, i do know that. i want to know which is the better method of doing it. Is it downloading different files of diff. sizes from the server and then calculating the bandwidth or is it good to download fixed size file from server and then calculate bandwidth depending on that? my question is not how to calculate bandwidth/

Comment: Certainly if you take into consideration the files that are being downloaded (I guess much more than 50 KB) it would be more accurate. As files are downloaded, update the speed (total time and total bytes change). It all depends what you need : just to display an approximate speed before downloading (download a 50 KB temp file) or during the download (use the downloaded files).