# HttpClient Post with progress and MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: java, progress, apache-httpclient-4.x

I try to implement an progress while uploading an file with `HttpClient` 4.3.3 and `MultipartEntityBuilder`

So actually i execute a post request with the following code

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
HttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);

MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.addPart("filea", new FileBody(filea));
entityBuilder.addPart("fileb", new FileBody(fileb));

final HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
httpPost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Any idea how to get the actual progress from the upload? I searched a lot - but the examples are for android and not plain java or an older version of `HttpClient` and didn't work for me...

Comment: Hi Please refer this link Its solve my problem. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932821/httpclient-post-with-progress-and-multipartentitybuilder>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just found a solution for that:

You need an `HttpEntityWrapper` which counts the processed bytes and has a callback.

```
ProgressHttpEntityWrapper.ProgressCallback progressCallback = new ProgressHttpEntityWrapper.ProgressCallback() {

        @Override
        public void progress(float progress) {
            //Use the progress
        }

    }

httpPost.setEntity(new ProgressHttpEntityWrapper(entityBuilder.build(), progressCallback));
```

And here is the complete code from the `ProgressHttpEntityWrapper`: https://github.com/x2on/gradle-hockeyapp-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/de/felixschulze/gradle/util/ProgressHttpEntityWrapper.groovy

Main source for this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7319110/268795

Comment: Hi, I have used your solution for calculating uploaded file size and remaining file size but it differ from actual file size present in gallery. Do you have any idea? why the file size gets vary?

Comment: There is a delay between ProgressCallback reporting 100% creation and the HttpServer actually responding status ok, what accounts for the diference