# how to cancel upload process using MultipartEntityBuilder in android?

Tags: android, upload, http-post

I am using `MultipartEntityBuilder` class for uploading file.
Main source for this solution: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942382/3818147)

I want to ask how to cancel upload process in progress function of the `ProgressHttpEntityWrapper.ProgressCallback` class under special situation?
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be making the upload request inside some thread or asynctask. so just cancel or stop that thread or asynctask.

For asynctask you can use

task.cancel(true);