# API call missing header information for file transfer

Tags: json, java

i am writing a java code which will send a file to certain URL through a API call, but there is some information miss out during the **GET** response from the URL, it's seen like my file information missing which are display_name, file_type. The display_name will be the file name of my file 
 Here are the return JSON data

```
{  
   "data_id":"55229f05ab534b08b369c324311e2c99",
   "file_info":{  
      "display_name":"",
      "file_size":254,
      "file_type":"Not available",
      "file_type_description":"Not available",
      "md5":"8a0c92123d8ffefd95aa1d3dd239c3f7",
      "sha1":"1cfd579d81df680b64e2127296aac55566b95b59",
      "sha256":"a86758bed1a99e12d301fd8bc90749bef89685b9a9c93ad7fa6ee832cb6a7d4e",
      "upload_timestamp":"2016-11-22T05:12:42.374Z"
   },
```

here is my sample java source

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

    public class SentFile {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.25:8008/file");
         // File file = new File("testScanFile.txt");
         //FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
          FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("testScanFile.txt"));
          HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                   .addPart("bin", bin)
                //   .addPart("file",bin);
                   .build();
           post.addHeader("content-type","application/json");
           post.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
           post.setEntity(reqEntity);
          //InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
         // post.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
          String line = "";
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           // System.out.println(line);
           PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("data_id.txt"));
           ps.print(line);
           ps.close();
          }
         }

    }
```

if i try to add in .addPart("file", bin) under the HttpEntity class, it's show me some error message, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932821/httpclient-post-with-progress-and-multipartentitybuilder) is my reference link for the .addPart but when i executed the program, my compiler show me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from MultipartEntityBuilder to HttpEntity
    Syntax error on token ".", delete this token
    The method build() is undefined for the type SentFile
```

i also tested this code and no error show up but the display_name still missing

```
post.addHeader("content-type","application/json");
post.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really post the server API definition, however this example shows the facilities in the Apache Fluent [API](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html#addBinaryBody(java.lang.String,%20java.io.File,%20org.apache.http.entity.ContentType,%20java.lang.String)):

```
MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
    .addBinaryBody("bin"                 // Important! Defined by the server 
        , new File("testScanFile.txt")   // Not important, user defined
        , ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON   // Maybe ignored. Depends
        , "testScanFile.txt"             // User defined
).build();
```

Comment: i tested your provided code , it run with no error but my display name still empty

Comment: Please post the server API spec

Comment: can you provide me the link to server API spec ? thanks