# check user connection's bandwidth in android mobile app at runtime

Tags: android, bandwidth

i am working on an android application where i need to play find the connection's bandwidth at run time. i found out a solution on stack overflow itself saying that i can download a file from server and then by calculating size vs time , i can get the speed of connection.

[Check the bandwidth rate in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225791/check-the-bandwidth-rate-in-android)

Is this the best way (only way) to get accurate results ?
Thanks for sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just query for this information. Your Internet speed is determined and controlled by your `ISP`, not by your network interface or router.

So the only way you can get your (current) connection speed is by downloading a file from a close enough location and timing how long it takes to retrieve the file. For example:

```
static final String FILE_URL = "http://www.example.com/speedtest/file.bin";
static final long FILE_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 8; // 5MB in Kilobits

long mStart, mEnd;
Context mContext;
URL mUrl = new URL(FILE_URL);
HttpURLConnection mCon = (HttpURLConnection)mUrl.openConnection();
mCon.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

if(mCon.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    mStart = new Date().getTime();

    InputStream input = mCon.getInputStream();
    File f = new File(mContext.getDir("temp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), "file.bin");
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    int read_len = 0;

    while((read_len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fo.write(buffer, 0, read_len);
    }
    fo.close();
    mEnd = new Date().getTime();
    mCon.disconnect();

    return FILE_SIZE / ((mEnd - mStart) / 1000);
}
```

This code, when sightly modified (you need `mContext` to be a valid context) and executed from inside an `AsyncTask` or a worker thread, will download a remote file and return the speed in which the file was downloaded in Kbps.

Comment: What is 'buffer' here?

Answer (score 4):

Facebook released a library for this: You can try this

https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class